# An irreducible polynomial in a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ has no multiple roots in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a subfield and $f\in K[t]$ an irreducible polynomial. Show that $f$ has no multiple roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

If I understand this question correctly, I must show that there is no $a \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $(t-a)^n|f$ in $F[t]$ with $n>1$. So suppose $(t-a)^2|f$ and $f=(t-a)^2h$. Then we have $f'=2(t-a)h+(t-a)^2h' \Rightarrow (t-a)|f'$ so $\gcd(f,f'$) is not constant. Therefore $f$ is divisible by some square of non-constant polynomial in $F[t]$, which is a contradiction. Is my argument correct? Thank you.

Comment: A gcd argument with $f$, $f'$ will do it. No need to say square of a non-constant polynomial, polynomial of positive degree less than the degree of $f$ is enough.

Comment: Could you explain the gcd argument explicitly? Since $(t-a)$ is not necessarily in $F[t]$ so how do I find a non-trivial divisor of $f$? Thank you!

Comment: I wrote it out, so you would see that the gcd argument works out fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can assume $f$ has degree $\ge 2$. Suppose that $f$ and $f'$ are relatively prime as polynomial over $K$. Then (Bezout) there exist polynomials $u(t)$ and $v(t)$, *with coefficients in* $K$ such that $uf+vf'=1$.

But then $f$ and $f'$ cannot have a common root in any field extension of $K$, for such a root would have to be a root of the polynomial $1$. In particular, they cannot have a common root in $\mathbb{C}$. This contradicts the assumption that $f$ has a double root in $\mathbb{C}$.

So $f$ and $f'$ are not relatively prime as polynomials over $K$. Let $g=\gcd(f,f')$. Then $g$ is a polynomial over $K$ of degree $\ge 1$ and less than the degree of $f$, and $g$ divides $f$. This contradicts the irreducibility of $f$ over $K$.

Answer (score 3):

Given a root $\alpha$ of $f(x)$, $f(x)$ (divided by his director coefficient but who cares, we have coefficients in a field) is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Thus there cannot be another polynomial with lower degree such that $p(\alpha)=0$.

If $\alpha$ is a double root for $f(x)$, then $f'(x)$ is again a polynomial in $K[x]$ and of course $f'(\alpha)=0$. But his degree is lower then $f(x)$. We conclude that $f'(x) \equiv 0$. Since we are working in a subfield of $\mathbb C$, thus a field of characteristic $0$, we know that this implies $f(x)\equiv 0$ , absurd.

Comment: You haven't used the fact that we're working in a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.  For instance, why does your argument not apply to $K = \mathbb{F}_2(t)$ with $f(x) = x^2 + t \in K[x]$?

Comment: I implicitly left out the last part: $f'$ must be $0$ everywhere, thus $f$ is costant, thus $f$ is equal to $0$ everywhere, absurd. This is not true in the latter case since deriving for example $x^p$ you get $0$ in $\mathbb Z_p[x]$.

Comment: I'm glad you have completed your argument.  Why not add it to your answer?